# Leaflet integrating with collapse

Tags: leaflet

I have integrated Leaflet in my website. But, if I set the map in a collapse, the map doesn't become fully visible.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0YXk.png)

```
  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([33.841954, 10.995487], 11);
  const mainLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}? access_token={accessToken}', { attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>', maxZoom: 18, enter: [33.841954, 10.995487], id: 'mapbox/streets-v11', tileSize: 512, zoomOffset: -1, accessToken: 'AccessToken'});
  mainLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call after expanding the view `map.invalidateSize()`